# Rails 6 create link with token inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my API app I'm using Rails 6 where I override devise `reset_password_instructions` to pass firebase deeplink with user's token.

The construction of link is quite complicated, whole link passed in email should be like:

`https://my_app.page.link/?link=https://api.company.jobs/web/reset_password?reset_password_token=12345&apn=com.company.production&isi=1501852500&ibi=com.jobs.company&ifl=https://www.company.jobs/`

So the simplest way to handle it is the ugliest way, which I used:

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  PASSWORD_URL_1 = 'https://my_app.page.link/?link=https://api.company.jobs/web/reset_password?reset_password_token='
  PASSWORD_URL_2 = '&apn=com.company.production&isi=1501852500&ibi=com.jobs.company&ifl=https://www.company.jobs/'

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    @reset_password_url = PASSWORD_URL_1 + token + PASSWORD_URL_2
    super
  end
end
```

so in `reset_password_instructions` I've passed it:

```
<%= link_to 'Reset password', @reset_password_url, class: 'button' %>
```

But it's ugly as hell, how to do so in a proparate way? I don't even know what are the alternatives and these link will change depends on environment so I cannot create 6 instance variables to handle all environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rails credentials](https://medium.com/@kirill_shevch/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc) to store different values per environment, like:

```
reset_email:
  url: "https://my_app.page.link"
  company: "https://api.company.jobs/web/reset_password"
```

and then use those values from inside the class, for example:

```
def password_url
  "#{Rails.application.credentials.reset_email[:url]}/?link=https://api.company.jobs/web/reset_password?reset_password_token="
end
```

you can add the other values there in the string, or break it up to make it more readable.

Comment: So still you have to split and use `+` to pass the token. I'm wondering is there any way to not split these links and user eg. interpolation?

Comment: well, yeah, you can interpolate those values, something like `"#{url}/?#{company_url}?token=#{token}&...."` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string interpolation you want to use [`Hash#to_query`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_query) from ActiveSupport which will properly handle escaping the urls passed in the query string:

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    @reset_password_url = reset_password_url(token)
    super
  end

  private
  def reset_password_url(token)
    "https://my_app.page.link?" + {
      link: "https://api.company.jobs/web/reset_password?reset_password_token=#{token}",
      apn:  'com.company.production',
      isi:  1501852500,
      ibi:  'com.jobs.company',
      ifl:  'https://www.company.jobs/'
    }.to_query
  end
end
```

The [URI module](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) is also a really good place to look if you want to build URIs programmatically. This can also be refactored out into a helper method which would remove the need for overriding the mailer completely.